# Java Related, regarding: If-Else, Do-While, Try-Catch

Tags: java

I am in my first semester of a Java Course. I am struggling to understand how I put exclusiveness on a statement.  I am writing a Class for an Object Couch. I have tried to build a well formed class, but for the outcome from my main, in the console it must only have 4 or 8 legs on the couch. There is no user input as I am hard coding the variables, but I want to be sure that if I hard code for 5 legs it will stop me or an error message will pop up. Any suggestions?

```
public void setNbrLegs(int nbrLegs){
    if ((nbrLegs == 2) || (nbrLegs == 4)){
        this.nbrLegs = nbrLegs;
    }
}
```

I tried putting an "else"  with a message that that number is bad, but what is did was bypass my error message and just insert the incorrect number ofLegs as 5.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking for the opposite: a condition where you must fail. From there, you can use runtime exceptions to ensure a few things:

1. The invalid state is not applied
2. A developer passing this invalid state will get an exception, and have a clear reason to fix their code
3. You no longer have to worry about invalid state further on in the method (i.e. legs will only be `2` or `4` further on).

In doing so, your method may end up looking like this:

```
public void setNbrLegs(int legs) {
    if (legs != 4 && legs != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only have 2 or 4 legs");
    }
    this.nbrLegs = legs;
}
```

This preconditional checking is also good to do early in your methods (fast-fail), as it will prevent excess work being done for a method that will only "fail".

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me another way to look at this.

Comment: @Jodyoda If this answer resolved your concern then please consider accepting it. Accepted answers are more helpful for the community.